# Puppet: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected

Tags: puppeteer, chrome-aws-lambda

We have written a Print PDF lambda function that generates a PDF file using puppeteer from HTML content.
The lambda function uses the packages chrome-aws-lambda and puppeteer-core to generate PDF content from HTML. The puppeteer error is occurring in our QA when images are included in any HTML content, either as a background-image or an  tag.  When no image is included, the PDF gets generated successfully.

We are using the following:
npm install chrome-aws-lambda@8.0.2 puppeteer-core@8.0.0 --save-prod

Below is the exception
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!",
"stack": [
"Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!",
"    at /var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:51:147",
"    at /var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:62",
"    at Array.map ()",
"    at Object.emit (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:51:43)",
"    at CDPSession.emit (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:72:22)",
"    at CDPSession._onClosed (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:247:14)",
"    at Connection._onClose (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:128:21)",
"    at WebSocket. (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/NodeWebSocketTransport.js:17:30)",
"    at WebSocket.onClose (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)",
"    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)"
]
}

### below is the code snippet:

```
async function getBrowser() {
  if (puppeteer) {
    return await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  }
  // if running in lambda return chromium lambda
  if (chromium) {
    return await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
      headless: chromium.headless,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
    });
  }
}

export const html2pdf = async (html = '', url = '', format = 'Legal') => {
  let myBrowser = await getBrowser();
  const page = await myBrowser.newPage();
  const loaded = page.waitForNavigation({
    waitUntil: 'load'
  });

  if (html) {
    await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  } else if (url) {
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  }
  // await page.setViewport({ isMobile: true, width: 375, height: 667 });
  await loaded;

  const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: format });
  await page.close();
  await myBrowser.close();
  return pdf;
};
```

---

according to some stackoverflow posts we have increased the ephemeral storage and memory to their perspective max: 10240 MB .
Any suggestions as to a solution or how to debug?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's never a navigation because setContent doesn't navigate.

Which means you're closing the browser before page.waitNavigation finishes.

I would just remove the waitForNavigation, page.goto should have that covered anyway.

Comment: so remove this code block? const loaded = page.waitForNavigation({
    waitUntil: 'load'
  });   How does this remove the race condition? how come it works partially to begin with?

Comment: Yes because setContent doesn't cause a navigation (I believe) and page.goto will wait for one anyway